# How to rename files based on CSV file with FOR /F loop?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, rename

I'm trying to automate renaming of files based on a CSV such as the one shown below:

Name,FullName

John,JohnDoe

Jane,JaneDoe

Joe,JoeDoe

Let's say I have 3 text files within the same folder of my .bat called John.txt, Jane.txt, Joe.txt and I want to rename John.txt to JohnDoe.txt, etc.

I am getting "The system cannot find the file specified" no matter how much I alter the filepath in my rename. Here is a basic rundown of what I have. What am I doing wrong here or what other way should I approach this? I appreciate all feedback.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set csvpath=C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Documents\BatchExamples\stuff.csv

FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=," %%g IN (!csvpath!) do (
    set person=%%g
    set name=%%h

    echo My name is !person! and my full name is !name!

    rename !person!.txt !name!.txt
)

pause
```

Comment: Is the script in the same folder as the CSV files? If it isn't, that would cause the error and you'd have to `cd C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Documents\BatchExamples` at the top of the script before doing any renaming.

Comment: …`cd /D "%UserProfile%\OneDrive\…`…

Comment: You have an error in your parenthesized `for` command; ```!csvpath!``` should be ```"!csvpath!"```. In addition you should improve your syntax; ```set csvpath=C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Documents\BatchExamples\stuff.csv``` should read as ```set "csvpath=C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Documents\BatchExamples\stuff.csv"```, ```set person=%%g```, should be ```set "person=%%g"```, ```set name=%%h```, should be ```set "name=%%h"```, and ```rename !person!.txt !name!.txt``` should be ```rename "!person!.txt" "!name!.txt"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
@echo off

set "csvpath=C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Documents\BatchExamples\stuff.csv"

FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=," %%g IN (`findstr /v /c:":-:-:" "%csvpath%"`) do (
    echo My name is "%%g" and my full name is "%%h"

    rename "%~dp0\%%g.txt" "%%h.txt"
)

pause
```

This code is a bit cleaner and more robust, in that file paths and names can have special characters (like `&`) without breaking the script.

`findstr /v /c:"SEARCHSTRING" "FILEPATH"` tells `findstr` to print every line within FILEPATH excluding (`/v`) lines with SEARCHSTRING. This doesn't really change much from what you had previously, however it is a bit more robust.

In the `rename` command, I set it to `%~dp0` and then the file name, `%~dp0` is the path to where your `.bat` script is.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and advice! It's working for me now and I'm playing around with it some more to absorb what you just explained. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Jen No problem. If you want to mark my answer as the correct one, feel free to click the checkmark just under the downvote button on my answer, and we'll both get some points :).